# "make -C X" vs "cd X; make"

Tags: linux, makefile

I am wonder why these two commands return two different results. First one is:

```
[root@node30 par-run-d2]# make -C NQU/
make: Entering directory `/home/ut/gpgpu-sim/benchmarks/par-run-d2/NQU'
nvcc  -c -arch sm_11 --keep --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing \
        -I. -I/usr/local/cuda//include/ -I/home/ut/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C//common/inc/ \
          -L/home/ut/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C//lib -lcutil -DUNIX nqueen.cu -o nqueen 
nqueen.cu(681): warning: variable "start" was declared but never referenced

nqueen.cu(681): warning: variable "end" was declared but never referenced

nqueen.cu(681): warning: variable "start" was declared but never referenced

nqueen.cu(681): warning: variable "end" was declared but never referenced

gcc -g -c nqueen.cu.cpp -o nqueen.cu_o
echo ../../..
../../..
../../../scripts/gen_ptxinfo
Generating nqueen.ptxinfo...
make: *** [nqueen.cu_o] Error 255
make: Leaving directory `/home/ut/gpgpu-sim/benchmarks/par-run-d2/NQU'
```

And the second one is:

```
[root@node30 par-run-d2]# cd NQU/
[root@node30 NQU]# make
g++  -g nqueen.cu_o -L../../../libcuda/ -lcuda \
        -L/home/ut/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C//lib -lcutil \
        -L../../../src/ -lgpgpusim \
        -L../../../src/intersim -lintersim \
        -L../../../src/cuda-sim/ -lgpgpu_ptx_sim \
        -lm -lz -lGL   -o gpgpu_ptx_sim__nqueen
rm -rf *.cpp*.i *.cpp*.ii *.cu.c *.cudafe*.* *.fatbin.c *.cu.cpp *.linkinfo *.cpp_o core *.cubin cubin.bin *_o *.hash nqueen
```

Any idea why "make -C X" differs from "cd X/; make" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence `cd X; make` is changing the current directory of the invoking shell (the interactive shell of your terminal). Make that a sub-shell like `(cd X; make)` to avoid that, which is much longer to type than `make -C X` which does the `chdir` syscall inside the `make` process so cannot change the working directory of the parent process (your interactive shell usually).

Also the `-w` flag behavior would be different. And most recursive `$(MAKE)` in `Makefile`-s are doing a `-C somesubdir`

PS. Remember that the `cd` shell built-in invokes the [chdir(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/chdir.2.html) syscall which has no effect on the parent process.

Comment: I don't see how changing the working directory of the sub-shell is relevant here, since there are no commands in the subshell after `make`. And I don't see how the `-w` flag behavior would be different. Could you give us a Makefile that demonstrates the effects?